# Grouped product parent vs Grouped product child in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using PDF packing plugin ([WooCommerce PDF Invoices](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices)) to create packing slips after order is placed. And [Product Bundles](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-bundles/) plugin for bundled products.

In those PDFs I want to differentiate between the container of a bundled product and its child.

Currently I am using this from Product Bundles:

[`if(wc_pb_is_bundle_container_cart_item($item)  )`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/bundles/bundles-functions-reference/#wc_pb_is_bundle_container_cart_item)

it checks if an item is container of a bundled product then returns true. I need a similar function which would return true if the item is child or is inside a bundle.

here is the code of packing slip pdf body:

```
<?php
/**
 * PDF packing slip template body.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to youruploadsfolder/woocommerce-pdf-invoices/templates/packing-slip/simple/yourtemplatename/body.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce PDF Invoices will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @author  Bas Elbers
 * @package WooCommerce_PDF_Invoices/Templates
 * @version 0.0.1
 */

$templater                      = WPI()->templater();
$order                          = $templater->order;
$formatted_shipping_address     = $order->get_formatted_shipping_address();
$formatted_billing_address      = $order->get_formatted_billing_address();
$line_items                     = $order->get_items( 'line_item' );
$color                          = $templater->get_option( 'bewpi_color_theme' );
?>

<table>
    <tr class="title">
        <td colspan="3">
            <h2><?php _e( 'Packing Slip', 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices' ); ?></h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="information">
        <td width="50%">
            <?php echo nl2br( $templater->get_option( 'bewpi_company_address' ) ); ?>
        </td>

        <td>
            <?php
            if ( $templater->get_option( 'bewpi_show_ship_to' ) && ! empty( $formatted_shipping_address ) && $formatted_shipping_address !== $formatted_billing_address && ! $templater->has_only_virtual_products( $line_items ) ) {
                printf( '<strong>%s</strong><br />', __( 'Ship to:', 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices' ) );
                echo $formatted_shipping_address;
            }
            ?>
        </td>

        <td>
            <?php echo $formatted_billing_address; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="heading" bgcolor="<?php echo $color; ?>;">
            <th>
                <?php _e( 'Qty', 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices' ); ?>
            </th>

            <th>
                <?php _e( 'Product', 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices' ); ?>
            </th>

            <th>

                <?php _e( 'SKU', 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices' ); ?>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    //$parentItem = 0;
    foreach ( $line_items as $item_id => $item ) { 

        $product = BEWPI_WC_Order_Compatibility::get_product( $order, $item );


        if(wc_pb_is_bundle_container_cart_item($item)  ){
        ?>

        <tr class="item">
            <td width="10%">
                <?php  echo $item['qty']; ?>
                <?php // print_r($item); die(); ?>
            </td>

            <td width="65%">
                <?php
                echo $item['name'];

                do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', $item_id, $item, $order );

                $templater->wc_display_item_meta( $item, true );
                $templater->wc_display_item_downloads( $item, true );

                do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order );
                ?>
            </td>

            <td width="25%">

                <?php echo $product && $product->get_sku() ? $product->get_sku() : '-'; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <?php  }  else   { ?>
        <tr class="item">
            <td width="10%" style="float:right;">
                <?php  echo $item['qty']; ?>
            </td>

            <td width="5%" style="float:right;">
                <?php
                echo '----'.$item['name'];
                //echo 'i m child';

                do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', $item_id, $item, $order );

                $templater->wc_display_item_meta( $item, true );
                $templater->wc_display_item_downloads( $item, true );

                do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order );
                ?>
            </td>

            <td width="25%" style="float:right;">

                <?php echo $product && $product->get_sku() ? $product->get_sku() : '-'; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <?php }} ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="notes">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php
            // Customer notes.
            if ( $templater->get_option( 'bewpi_show_customer_notes' ) ) {
                // Note added by customer.
                $customer_note = BEWPI_WC_Order_Compatibility::get_customer_note( $order );
                if ( $customer_note ) {
                    printf( '<strong>' . __( 'Note from customer: %s', 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices' ) . '</strong><br />', nl2br( $customer_note ) );
                }

                // Notes added by administrator on 'Edit Order' page.
                foreach ( $order->get_customer_order_notes() as $custom_order_note ) {
                    printf( '<strong>' . __( 'Note to customer: %s', 'woocommerce-pdf-invoices' ) . '</strong><br />', nl2br( $custom_order_note->comment_content ) );
                }
            }
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to append `----` infront of the name of product only if the product is part of any bundle. just want this check, I cant figure out how can I do that

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that you are using *[Cart Functions](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/bundles/bundles-functions-reference/#section-2)* instead of *[Order Functions](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/bundles/bundles-functions-reference/#section-3)*.

First you need to use `wc_pb_is_bundle_container_order_item` instead of `wc_pb_is_bundle_container_cart_item` as we are checking against **Order Items**.

Further to that [`wc_pb_is_bundled_order_item`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/bundles/bundles-functions-reference/#wc_pb_is_bundled_order_item) is the check you should be using to determine if the product is a child item of an container item. This is important because it will check if item *has a parent container* so your code can scale when you also have non-bundled items in order as well.

Below is just partial relevant code from question.

```
<?php  }  else   { ?>
    <tr class="item">
        <td width="10%" style="float:right;">
            <?php  echo $item['qty']; ?>
        </td>

        <td width="5%" style="float:right;">
            <?php
            // Adding a check to see if current item is a child of a container
            $item_name_padding = wc_pb_is_bundled_order_item( $item ) ? '----': '';
            echo $item_name_padding . $item['name'];
            //echo 'i m child';

            do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', $item_id, $item, $order );

            $templater->wc_display_item_meta( $item, true );
            $templater->wc_display_item_downloads( $item, true );

            do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order );
            ?>
        </td>

        <td width="25%" style="float:right;">

            <?php echo $product && $product->get_sku() ? $product->get_sku() : '-'; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>


    <?php }} ?>
```

Comment: @SyedHarisAliGhaznavi ahh! I missed a crucial detail. You were using *Cart* related functions whereas working with *Order* data. Updated my answer with correct functions.